# Shape of $x^2+y^2+|y^m|=1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was messing around on a graphing application when I came across the formula:
$$1 = x^2 + y^2 + \left| y^m \right| ; m\gt 1$$

The graphs produced by this function appear to be a squarish-ellipse shape. I was wondering if there was a general name for this shape.

[Here is an example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2%2B%7Cy%5E8%7C%3D1) of the shape for $m=8$ on Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very similar shape is the [Superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) given by the formula:
$$\left|\frac{x}{a}\right|^n+\left|\frac{y}{b}\right|^n=1$$

Your curve is very similar but without the requirement that both $x$ and $y$ have the same power (a generalization of the superellipse). Your two powers of $y$ could be replaced with one without much difference in shape as in your graph $y^2$ dominates for certain values of $y$ and $|y^8|$ dominates for other values of $y$.